# Разница между LayoutInflater.from и getLayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У нас есть activity я могу сделать так

```
LayoutInflater.from(activity)
```

или так

```
activity.layoutInflater
```

в чем разница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта чаще всего будут работать без особой разницы, но есть небольшое различие.

**LayoutInflater.from**(activity) ждет Context и там происходит:

```
LayoutInflater LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**activity.layoutInflater** использует

`getWindow().getLayoutInflater();`

В этом то и разница, дело в том что getWindow обращается уже к закешированному LayoutInflater и работает через Provider. Более того вы получите уже Inflater с параметрами, там есть attr, которые могут быть разные например при разных стилях, темах приложения, если поменялись. Специально такое сделать возможно, но думаю в нормальных кейсах сложно встретить. Получается если есть возможность, то лучше использовать getLayoutInflater() это вызов будет быстрей (Ооооочень незначительно) и получит актуальный Inflater, в другом случае вы получите LayoutInalfater от текущего Context.

Comment: что такое getWindow ?

Comment: можете задать этот вопрос отдельно. Вкратце это ссылка на базовый абстрактный класс Window, который будет использоваться WindowManager при создании корневого DecorView.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню принятый ответ.

Разницы по сути никакой, единственная имплементация `Window` это `PhoneWindow`, которая только и делает, что кэширует инфлейтер в переменную, чтобы быстрее возвращать.

```
mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Так что при одинаковом контексте(активити) результат будет абсолютно одинаков.